# MySQL Stored Procedure Dupplication Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I hope someone can help. I have created this stored procedure to pull some infromation from different tables and when i tun it I get many duplicates, I was wondering if there was a way of sorting it?

```
use ICA
if exists(
    select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
    where SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'ICASchema'
    and SPECIFIC_NAME = N'candidateOffer'
    )
    drop procedure ICASchema.candidateOffer
go

create procedure ICASchema.candidateOffer @candidateID INT
    as
begin

select c.CandidateID,c.CandidateName, ca.CourseID, co.CourseName, o.OfferID, ot.OfferTypePoints
    from [ICASchema].[tblCandidate] c 
    join [ICASchema].[tblCandidateOffer] o on c.CandidateID = o.CandidateID
    join [ICASchema].[tblOffer] ot on o.offerID = ot.OfferType
    join [ICASchema].[tblCandidateApplication] ca on ca.CourseID = ca.CourseID
    join [ICASchema].[tblCourse] co on co.CourseName = co.CourseName
    where c.CandidateID = @candidateID
    --ORDER BY co.CourseName
    GROUP BY  co.CourseName, c.CandidateID,c.CandidateName, ca.CourseID, o.OfferID, ot.OfferTypePoints
end
go
```

Thanks

Graham

Comment: Add the `order by` after the `group by`, not before.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That part is already commented.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * from (select distinct c.CandidateID,c.CandidateName, ca.CourseID, co.CourseName, o.OfferID, ot.OfferTypePoints
    from [ICASchema].[tblCandidate] c 
    join [ICASchema].[tblCandidateOffer] o on c.CandidateID = o.CandidateID
    join [ICASchema].[tblOffer] ot on o.offerID = ot.OfferType
    join [ICASchema].[tblCandidateApplication] ca on ca.CourseID = ca.CourseID
    join [ICASchema].[tblCourse] co on co.CourseName = co.CourseName
    where c.CandidateID = @candidateID

    GROUP BY  co.CourseName, c.CandidateID,c.CandidateName, ca.CourseID, o.OfferID, ot.OfferTypePoints) tablealias order by CourseName
```

Comment: Hey, it still has 12 results instead of the expected two. :(

Comment: I thought you just need to sort the data. You can use distinct to get uniq record only. I have updated the query please try and let me know the result

Comment: can you please load you data in sql fiddle

Comment: Never used it before and cant get it to build (im very very rusty on SQL) Here is the script from my DB

Comment: 3 Mr J Bloggs          2 BSc Computer Science 1 280
3 Mr J Bloggs          2 BSc Computer Science 2 240
3 Mr J Bloggs          3 BSc Computer Science 1 280
3 Mr J Bloggs          3 BSc Computer Science 2 240
3 Mr J Bloggs          2 FnD Computer Science 1 280
3 Mr J Bloggs          2 FnD Computer Science 2 240
3 Mr J Bloggs          3 FnD Computer Science 1 280
3 Mr J Bloggs          3 FnD Computer Science 2 240

Comment: I tried loading the data from the extract in my first post under My Database and it wouldn't work, it was coming up with an error and I don't know how to sort it?

Comment: can you please generate you database script with schema+data

Comment: I have tried, I dont know how. Can you do it form the script above?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/

Comment: I followed that guide to extract it all and when I try and import into fiddle it just errors saying the Schema is too large, and when I try and do it in chunks it juts errors.....

Comment: you can upload the file somewhere like dropbox and give link here

Comment: I have loaded the database. Now tell me what do you want to achieve for CandidateID =3

Comment: Hi there, I was away a couple of days. A friend looked at my code and then used the Query designer (I didn't know about) The working result was :

Comment: [code]SELECT        c.CandidateID, c.CandidateName, ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferTypePoints, ICASchema.tblCourse.CourseName
FROM            ICASchema.tblCandidate AS c INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer ON c.CandidateID = ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer.CandidateID INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblOffer ON ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer.CandidateOfferID = ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferID INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblCourse ON ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferID = ICASchema.tblCourse.OfferTypeID
WHERE        (c.CandidateID = '3')
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Following example is for creating a simple Proc_GetAllUsers stored procedure. This will solve your duplication issue.

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Proc_GetAllUsers` 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_GetAllUsers( )
BEGIN

-- your sql queries 
select *  FROM users;

END

Go

Comment: I cant get this working at all, looking at it it seems to do the same as the if exists procedure I already had?

Answer (score 0):

This was the working solution.

[code]SELECT        c.CandidateID, c.CandidateName, ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferTypePoints, ICASchema.tblCourse.CourseName
FROM            ICASchema.tblCandidate AS c INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer ON c.CandidateID = ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer.CandidateID INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblOffer ON ICASchema.tblCandidateOffer.CandidateOfferID = ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferID INNER JOIN
                         ICASchema.tblCourse ON ICASchema.tblOffer.OfferID = ICASchema.tblCourse.OfferTypeID
WHERE        (c.CandidateID = '3')
[/code]